# How to encrypt database SQLite using Adobe AIR 2.0

Tags: database, sqlite, air, adobe, encryption

i just wanna ask how to encrypt database using adobe air 2.0. I found some codes using Adobe air 1.5. here the codes:

```
// Include AIRAliases.js to use air.* shortcuts
var conn = new air.SQLConnection(); 
conn.addEventListener(air.SQLEvent.OPEN, openHandler); 
conn.addEventListener(air.SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler); 
var dbFile = air.File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("DBSample.sqlite"); 

var encryptionKey = new air.ByteArray(); 
encryptionKey.writeUTFBytes("Some16ByteString"); // This technique is not secure! 

conn.openAsync(dbFile, air.SQLMode.CREATE, null, false, 1024, encryptionKey); 

function openHandler(event) 
{ 
    air.trace("the database opened successfully"); 
} 

function errorHandler(event) 
{ 
    if (event.error.errorID == 3138) 
    { 
        air.trace("Incorrect encryption key"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        air.trace("Error message:", event.error.message); 
        air.trace("Details:", event.error.details); 
    } 
}
```

it doesn't work. it just shows error : **air.SQLMode is not an object**

anybody can fix it? Thanks

Comment: it's strange to see those "air.". Try to write proper imports and refer directly to class names. SQLMode is in flash.data, not air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the air.* aliases is because the example is intended to be used in JavaScript. If you're using ActionScript you'll need to remove the air.* aliases and just import the classes instead.

For JavaScript, since there is no "import" statement, the AIR team created a file airaliases.js that creates aliases for all the AIR classes, so that you don't have to use the fully-qualified class name every time you want to use the class.